# Route following simulation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, maps, simulation

I am working on moving a map annotation along a route that has been mapped out in iOS, but I wanted it to follow the path given for the directions. So to be clear, I want a simulation of the user following the route of the map without actually doing the route. I have tried doing research and yes, I have seen the breadcrumb tutorial but I am really unsure how to go about following a route as described. Is there some way to get the map with the route broken down into points/data?

Any help or links are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change and animate the coordinates of the annotation along an array of coordinates.
But this requires that you have the "route" as sequence of coordinates. The apple route you will not get as coordinates. 
You could use `OpenStreetMap` to get a vector based route (coordinates).

Comment: Is there any mapping api that would give the route broken down well enough to follow it in a simulation style?

Comment: only OpenStreetMap provides coordinates, but has lower quality.

Comment: Yeah, I might try using http://map.project-osrm.org/ but if that does not work may fall back on trying to find a way of getting the CGPath that iOS uses to make the overlay, though I'm doubting it's something Apple allows developers to get to.

Comment: My concern for these projects like OpenStreetMap is the maintenance and quality, as you mentioned before.

Comment: No you will not get it! professional vector data (tom tom, navteq) are handled as secret data. forget it.